# Appending data from ajax to html select tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-select

How can I append the data from **API** to a select tag in html.

This is my **javascript** code.

```
 var options = '';
 for (var i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
      options += '<option value="' + data.data[i].projectName + '">' + data.data[i].projectName + '</option>';
}
$("#selectProjectName").append(options);
```

This is my **html** code.

```
<select id="selectProjectName" class="form-control show-tick selectpicker" title="Choose project name">

</select>
```

The data is shown in the console of the browser, but it is not appended to the select tag while hard coded values are shown in the select tag.

Using ***AdminBSBMaterialDesign-master*** template.

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share so that everyone understands what is happening and why that might be happening

Comment: You can check my answer below and check whether your data is similar to the data I posted. Otherwise, please post the sample minimum data here.

Comment: Or, use `data.data.length` as in my answer instead of `data.total`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you're using selectpicker, so after you change anything in the select element you need to refresh it using $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");

This is in the documentation [here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh).

Also, there's nothing apparently wrong with your method of appending it, as long as data.total returns the length of it (otherwise, use **.length**) but just as a FYI you can use the following syntax:

```
$('#select').append($('<option>', {value:1, text:'One'}));
```

To make things easier and nicer for you.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try .length** instead of .total

```
var options = '';

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 options += '<option value="' + data[i].projectName + '">' + data[i].projectName + '</option>';
}

$("#selectProjectName").append(options);
$("#selectProjectName").selectpicker("refresh");
```

Comment: can you console.log on the data variable just to make sure we're actually receiving data? Thanks

Comment: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
{projectId: "1", projectName: "voda", projectManager: "nande", resourceCount: "1", startDate: "2018-09-27 09:50:52", …}
1
:
{projectId: "2", projectName: "dialog", projectManager: "kushi", resourceCount: "1", startDate: "2018-09-27 09:50:49", …}
2
:
{projectId: "4", projectName: "Omobio system dashboard", projectManager: "kushari", resourceCount: "1", startDate: "2018-09-27 14:58:25", …}
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: I updated the answer to have data[i] instead of data.data. Didn't the answer from @RafaelGuglielmi work-- the one with selectpicker refresh?

Comment: Just tried is with data[i]. The data is received and can we view by a console.log but it ain't appending to the select tag.

Comment: @RafaelGuglielmi said that you're using a library to implement your select, he mentioned to put $(element).selectpicker("refresh");
Added that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your data is key value type

```js
var newOptions = {
    'red' : 'Red',
    'blue' : 'Blue',
    'green' : 'Green',
    'yellow' : 'Yellow'
}; // get this data from server
var selectedOption = 'green';

var select = $('#selectProjectName');
var options = select.prop('options');

$.each(newOptions, function(val, text) {
    options[options.length] = new Option(text, val);
});
select.val(selectedOption);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectProjectName" class="form-control show-tick selectpicker" title="Choose project name">

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using string concatenation, you can use jquery style of creating `option` element and appending the same as below.

Please check whether your data structure is similar to the one below according to the code that you are trying.

Otherwise better to use `data.data.length` instead of `data.total`

```js
var data = {
  total: 3,
  data: [
    {
      projectName: 'jquery'
    },
    {
      projectName: 'reactjs'
    },
    {
      projectName: 'angular'
    }
  ]
};

 for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
      var option = $('<option>', {
        value: data.data[i].projectName,
        html: data.data[i].projectName
      });
      $("#selectProjectName").append(option);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectProjectName" class="form-control show-tick selectpicker" title="Choose project name">

</select>
```

Comment: This works when given hard coded data in a 'data' array. 
But it doesn't work with data received from the API

Comment: Hi @MinulMindula, then the issue might be because of the data structure would be different. Can you post the data as it is that you receive from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Use .length instead of .total
Inside the loop, create each option element and add them one by one to the select element:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var opt = $('<option></option>');
        opt.attr('value', data.data[i].projectName).text(data.data[i].projectName);
        $("#selectProjectName").append(opt);
    }
```

Comment: Still nope. 
Is there any other way to append json data received from API into html select tag?